# jquery mobile select works in fiddle, not in sandbox

Tags: select, jquery-mobile

I have [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/steveo_88/e5z0q99p/) (thanks to user named once) which behaves nicely: you select one option in the dropdown, and it shows a table column corresponding to that option and hides the three others.

html

```
</div>
<!-- /header -->
<div data-role='content'>
    <table class='mytable'>
        <caption style='text-align: left;'>Table A</caption>
        <thead>
            <TR>
                <TH align='left'>Type</TH>
                <TH align='left'>Amount</TH>
                <th colspan='4' scope='col'>
                    <label for='selmenu'></label>
                    <select id='selmenu' class='sel' data-native-menu='false' style='width: 100px'>
                        <option class='type1' value='type1'>type1</option>
                        <option class='type2' value='type2'>type2</option>
                        <option class='type3' value='type3'>type3</option>
                        <option class='type4' value='type4'>type4</option>
                    </select>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                <TH align=l eft>Cars</TH>
                <TD>5,000</TD>
                <TD class='exhaust type1'>7000</TD>
                <TD class='exhaust type2'>6000</TD>
                <TD class='exhaust type3'>5000</TD>
                <TD class='exhaust type4'>4000</TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                <TH align=l eft>Trucks</TH>
                <TD>45672</TD>
                <TD class='exhaust type1'>154</TD>
                <TD class='exhaust type2'>1.1</TD>
                <TD class='exhaust type3'>3.7</TD>
                <TD class='exhaust type4'>55.2</TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
            <TH align=l eft>Motorcycles</TH>
            <TD>224455</TD>
            <TD class='exhaust type1'>88</TD>
            <TD class='exhaust type2'>99</TD>
            <TD class='exhaust type3'>77</TD>
            <TD class='exhaust type4'>55</TD>
            </TR>
    </TABLE>
    <div data-role='footer'>
         <h4>my footer</h4>

    </div>
    <!-- /footer -->
</div>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.exhaust').hide();
$('.type1').show();

$('.sel').change(function () {
    $('.exhaust').hide();
    $('.' + this.value).show();
    $('.sel').val(this.value);
});
});
```

I have what I thought is identical code in my sandbox (identical html, identical js), but as you can see [image]

the behaviour is not the same.

I wondered if it was the position of the javascript (below the last "div" in the html, but moving it up into the head didn't work either.

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

problem "fixed" -- I use quotes because I don't know why this should work.

I removed all the non-applicable jquery functions from between the "script" tags. i.e. I removed the jquery related to buttons, radioset, datepicker. I kept only this:

```
//tabs and the hide/show column function
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.exhaust').hide();
$('.type1').show();

$('.sel').change(function () {
    $('.exhaust').hide();
    $('.' + this.value).show();
    $('.sel').val(this.value);
});
});
```

I really don't understand why that should work.